# Bash / Shell Script: Expect and Send not working properly

Tags: expect, send

My script is meant to be an experiment and time how long a firmware update process should take for a SSD drive. I'm trying to use "expect" and "send" to go through the firmware application's prompts before timing the actual process. However, the inputs are not going through and the script is stuck on the first prompt. What could I be doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

# Below is all to set up the FW Update

#mkdir /mnt/iso
#sudo mount -o loop ./Samsung_SSD_980_PRO_3B2QGXA7.iso /mnt/iso/
#mkdir /tmp/fwupdate
cd /tmp/fwupdate
#gzip -dc /mnt/iso/initrd | cpio -idv --no-absolute-filenames
cd root/fumagician/

# Use spawn to open the fumagician process
spawn ./fumagician

# Use expect to wait for the previous spawned process (fumagician) to output an expected string
# Use send to write y or n to the spawned process stdin
expect -ex {"Press any key to continue..."}
send "\r"

expect -ex {"Press any key to continue..."}
send "\r"

expect -ex {"Do you want to continue the firmware update? [Y/N]: "}
send "Y\n"

# Start timer
set start_time [clock seconds]

# There is another prompt that needs input (this is to run the actual FW update)
expect -ex {"Do you want to continue the firmware update? [Y/N]: "}
send "Y\n"

# Stop the timer and output execution time
expect -ex {"Firmware Update Completed"}
set end_time [clock seconds]
set elapsed_time [expr $end_time - $start_time]

expect -ex {"Press any key to EXIT..."}
send "\r"

puts "FW Update Time: $elapsed_time seconds"
```

And this is the result:

[image]

It's stuck in the first prompt without actually inputting anything.

Comment: `expect -ex {"Press any key to EXIT..."}` -- `-ex` means *exact* match but in the output `Press any key ...` is not quoted at all.

Comment: Run with `expect -d script.exp` to enable verbose debug output. You'll be able to see what expect is expecting and what it actually has.

Comment: What sexpect is saying is that expect (based on Tcl language) uses both `""` and `{}` for quoting. `expect {"hello"}` means you are expecting to see `"hello"` **with** the double quotes